# How to get one of repeatable text field liferay7 Freemarker

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I created a **Web content Dsiplay** ( ***Text as a repeatable field in structure*** ).
In the structure template i wanted to have **only the third element**.

I tried

> ${Text.getSiblings()[3].getData()}

But it doesn't work

I am using ***Liferay-7*** and ***Freemarker*** as *Stucture template*

***Thank you***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index fields start with **0** so the solution for the **3rd** element is :

> ${Text.getSiblings()[2].getData()}

Comment: Note that something like `${Text.siblings[2].data}` should also work, and it's nicer.